# How to use unofficial Google Trend API ( pyGTrends.py)

Tags: python, google-trends

I'm starting to learn python to make a program for crawling the web data. So I was googling and I found the google trend API, pyGTrend.py. But I can't use it.
I can found the same problem in google but no solution which I can understand. 
Please help me.

I just used the API as written at the API owner's website: [Programmatic Google Trends Api](http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/programmatic-google-trends-api/)

```
from pyGTrends import pyGTrends

connector = pyGTrends('googleID','passwaord')
connector.download_report(('banana', 'bread', 'bakery'),date='2008-4',geo='AT',scale=1)
print connector.csv()
```

error message is below,

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File ('Stdin') line1, in <Module>
File "C:\Pyhon27\Lib\site-pacakage\pyGTrends.py" line 115, in csv
KeyError: 'main'
```

Comment: The line number for your error is outside of the number of lines in the [pyGtrends.py file](https://github.com/suryasev/unofficial-google-trends-api/blob/master/pyGTrends.py). Have you modified it?

Comment: No. It was original code at github.

Comment: Might need to see the copy of your pyGTrends.py code then. Also, can you copy and paste the real source code and traceback? I noticed there are spelling mistakes in the text provided (for example 'passwaord' and 'pacakage') that suggest you probably typed them in by hand.

Comment: Hi, did you find out any solution that was working.

Answer (score 2):

you need to call it like this

```
from pytrends.pyGTrends import pyGTrends
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use it. Let me know if you would need further assistance:

```
from pytrends.pyGTrends import pyGTrends
import time
from random import randint
from IPython.display import display
from pprint import pprint
import urllib
import sys

google_username = "GMAIL_USERNAME"
google_password = "PASSWORD"
path = "."

terms = [
    "Image Processing",
    "Signal Processing",
    "Computer Vision",
    "Machine Learning",
    "Information Retrieval",
    "Data Mining"
]
# connect to Google Trends API
connector = pyGTrends(google_username, google_password)


for label in terms:
    print(label)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    #kw_string = '"{0}"'.format(keyword, base_keyword)
    connector.request_report(label, geo="US", date="01/2014 96m")
    # wait a random amount of time between requests to avoid bot detection
    time.sleep(randint(5, 10))
    # download file
    connector.save_csv(path, label)

for term in terms:
    data = connector.get_suggestions(term)
    pprint(data)
```

Comment: Hi Mona, 
I am using Python3.x, I used the same code as you wrote, but getting the error.
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

File "C:\Users\shivamkotwalia\Desktop\Testapp-shivam\Data Scraping\GoogleTrends.py", line 23, in <module>
    connector = pyGTrends(google_username, google_password)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytrends\pyGTrends.py", line 51, in __init__
    self._connect()